# Not defined id error with PHP

Tags: php, mysql

I have a little problem with a PHP code that was supposed to edit database table. Instead, it's giving me 'person not defined error - pointing to [lines 18 and 19](http://pastebin.com/ayK3UPkZ). And down the code, it says 'id' is undefined as well.

```
<?php
    $con = mysql_connect("localhost","myuser","mypass");
if (!$con)
  {
  die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
  }

    mysql_select_db("mydb", $con);
    if(!isset($_POST['submit'])){
    $q = "SELECT * FROM person WHERE id = $_GET[id]";
    $result = mysql_query($q) or die(mysql_error());
    $person = mysql_fetch_array($result);
    }
?>

<h1>You are Modifying A Record</h1>
  <form action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>" method="post">
    Name:<input type="text" name="myname" id="myname" value ="<?php echo $person['name']; ?>" /> <br />
    Description: <input type="text" name="mydescription" id="mydescription" value ="<?php echo $person['description']; ?>" /> <br />
    <input type="hidden" name="id" value="<?php echo $_GET['id']; ?>" />
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Modify" />

</form>

<?php
  if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
    $q = "UPDATE person SET `name`='$_POST[myname]', `description`='$_POST[mydescription]' WHERE id = $_POST[id]";
     mysql_query($q) or die(mysql_error());
     //header('Location: select.php');
     echo 'User has been modified successfully!';
     }else{

     }
?>
```

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Ok... first, any time you get data from $_REQUEST (including POST/GET/COOKIE data), you need to run mysql_real_escape_string on it before sending it to a database.

Comment: An advice, never use a variable inside a query string without proper escaping. Never do this: $q = "SELECT * FROM person WHERE id = $_GET[id]"; You should escape the data first using *mysqli_real_escape_string*, or in this case, simply casting it to int: $id = (int)$_GET['id']. Do a little research about SQL Injections.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, you're only conditionally defining `$person`. So, the first time you view the page, PHP should show an error.

You can fix this by adding an "else" clause:

```
if(!isset($_POST['submit'])){
    $q = "SELECT * FROM person WHERE id = $_GET[id]";
    $result = mysql_query($q) or die(mysql_error());
    $person = mysql_fetch_array($result);
}
else
{
    $person = array( 'name'=> '', 'description'=>'' );
}
```

As to $_GET[ 'id' ], are you going to the page with an `?id=<value>` in the url? If not, then $_GET[ 'id' ] will be undefined.

Comment: yes, I'm going to the page with ?id=<value>. so that's why I still can't work what might be the cause of the error. :(

Answer (score 1):

Since `$person` is defined only inside `if(!isset($_POST['submit']))` condition, if `submit` value is actually set, `$person` is not defined. That's what PHP is complaining about.

Answer (score 0):

This is because $person never gets created if the condition

```
if(!isset($_POST['submit'])){
```

is never met.

the way the code you showed is written doesn't make a lot of sense...

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, if you write a script that uses `$_GET['random_parameter_key_here']` without enclosing it in a conditional (ie `if (isset($_GET['param'])) { // do something }, it will print out a notice telling you that the variable has not been set.

Secondly, it could perhaps be that you were not retrieving a result from the database - check the result with `mysql_num_rows()` before attempting to use the object (if there was no result retrieved, $person will be null.